# How can i import null value in a csv file into my table of mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fgetcsv, import-csv

I would like to know how I can import a CSV file with null values ​​to my MySQL table.

This is the code I use in my PHP to import the CSV file to the MySQL table.

```
<?php

class csv extends mysqli {

    private $state_csv = false;
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct("localhost","","","");

        if ($this->connect_error) {
            echo "File to connect Database: ". $this ->connect_error;
        }
    }

    public function import($file=''){
        $file = fopen($file, 'r');

        while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {

            $value = "'". implode("','", $row) ."'";
            $q = "INSERT INTO test(cognome,nome,etichetta,email) VALUES(". $value .")";
            if ($this->query($q)) {
                $this->state_csv = true;
            } else {
                $this->state_csv = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My CSV file has this structure:

```
Test, Test,,test@test.com
```

If I import the CSV file with all the data I can import it but the problem is when there is a null value.

Comment: You should be able to allow null values in your MySQL database columns. Otherwise, if you can't adjust the database, replace null values with an empty variable (or space).

Comment: My database allow null values because when I do an import from mysql the null values are inserted in the table. The problem is when I import with my php I can't import null values or empty values.

Comment: Perhaps a var_dump of $value and/or $q will shed some light on what the problem actually is?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your sample CSV line

```
Test, Test,,test@test.com
```

is intended to become these four values for your database columns

```
 Test
  Test
 (null)
 test@test.com
```

But the third column appears as a zero-length string in your `$row` array, so it is inserted into the table as a zero length string.  Your INSERT statement will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(cognome,nome,etichetta,email) VALUES('Test',' Test','','test@test.com')
```

See the empty string for `etichetta`?

You need to replace this line:

```
 $value = "'". implode("','", $row) ."'";
```

with some smarter code to loop over the elements of `$row` interpreting them in a more sophisticated way.  Maybe something like this will work. (NOT debugged!)

```
$cols = [];
foreach ($row as $col) {
    if (strlen($row) == 0) array_push ($cols, "NULL")
    else array_push ($cols, "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($row) . "'")
}
$value = implode (',', $cols);
```

The result will be

```
INSERT INTO test(cognome,nome,etichetta,email) VALUES('Test',' Test',NULL,'test@test.com')
```

And, using real_escape_string will handle names like `O'Sullivan` and `Johnny ';DROP TABLE test;` correctly.

Comment: I have fixed your code and I used it but the import still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to say, "doesn't work" is not enough detail for us to help you.